# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_model_analysis' has no attribute 'EvalConfig'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get this error when I try to use the TensorFlow Model Analysis library to get some model metrics for my custom object detection model. I followed the instructions provided in the documentation to install the library and I am not sure what the issue is.

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma
from google.protobuf import text_format

eval_config = tfma.EvalConfig(
      model_specs = [tfma.ModelSpec(signature_name = "serving_default")],
      slicing_specs = [tfma.SlicingSpec()],
      metrics_specs = [tfma.MetricsSpec(metrics = 
                [
                  tfma.MetricConfig(class_name = "ExampleCount"),
                  tfma.MetricConfig(class_name = "SparseCategoricalCrossentropy"),
                  tfma.MetricConfig(class_name = "SparseCategoricalAccuracy"),
                  tfma.MetricConfig(class_name = "Precision"),
                  tfma.MetricConfig(class_name = "Recall"),
                  tfma.MetricConfig(class_name = "AUC"),
                  tfma.MetricConfig(class_name = "F1Score"),
                  tfma.MetricConfig(class_name = "MultiClassConfusionMatrixPlot")
                                                 
                ]
    )
  ]

)
```

I tried using the import

```
from tfx.components.evaluator.component import Evaluator
```

But I keep getting the error

> No module named 'proto'

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

With `tensorflow_model_analysis v0.39.0`, I could able to use `EvalConfig()`

```
!pip install tensorflow_model_analysis
import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma
print(tfma.__version__)
eval_config = tfma.EvalConfig()
```

**Output**

```
0.39.0
```